# Varying vertical spacing between rows in html form

Tags: html, css

I have a html form split into two columns and several rows with a combination of regular inputs and select inputs, as well as tooltip texts for each entry. The vertical spacing between each row varies, as shown in the below image. Why is this occurring and how could it be resolved? I tried setting the padding and margins for the inputs to 0, but it has not solved it. Even without the tooltip text, this still occurs.

[HTML Form Spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV0ez.png)

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8j3Lgz5d/4/

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: visible;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

.calculate1 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

select {
  text-align-last: center;
  background-color: #565656;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Geomanist;
  width: 75%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0;
}

input,
select,
option {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #565656;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Geomanist;
  width: 75%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
}

select:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
}

option:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
}

.submit {
  padding: 20px;
}

.submit input {
  background-color: #7c7c7c;
  width: 25%
}

.submit input:hover {
  outline: none;
  border-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -5px;
  left: 105%;
  overflow: visible;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: visible;
}

.tooltip2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.tooltip2 .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 80%;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -5px;
  right: 105%;
  overflow: visible;
}

.tooltip2:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class='calculate1'>
  <form name='calc' action='.' method='post'>
    <fieldset>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col'>
          <p>
            <div class='tooltip'>
              x
              <span class='tooltiptext'>abcd.
                        </span>
            </div>
          </p>
          <select name='x'>
            <option> a </option>
            <option> b </option>
            <option> c </option>
            <option> d </option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class='col'>
          <p>
            <div class='tooltip2'>
              y
              <span class='tooltiptext'>abcdef.
                        </span>
            </div>
          </p>
          <select name='y'>
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
            <option>c</option>
            <option>d</option>
            <option>e</option>
            <option>f</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col'>
          <p>
            <div class='tooltip'>
              z
              <span class='tooltiptext'>z.
                        </span>
            </div>
          </p>
          <p> <input type='text' name='z' required> </p>
        </div>
        <div class='col'>
          <p>
            <div class='tooltip2'>
              xx
              <span class='tooltiptext'>xx
                        </span>
            </div>
          </p>
          <p> <input type='text' name='xx' required></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col'>
          <p>
            <div class='tooltip'>
              yy
              <span class='tooltiptext'>yy
                        </span>
            </div>
          </p>
          <p> <input type='text' name='yy' required></p>
        </div>
        <div class='col'>
          <p>
            <div class='tooltip2'>
              zz
              <span class='tooltiptext'>abcdefghijk
                        </span>
            </div>
          </p>
          <select name='yy'>
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
            <option>c</option>
            <option>d</option>
            <option>e</option>
            <option>f</option>
            <option>g</option>
            <option>h</option>
            <option>i</option>
            <option>j</option>
            <option>k</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col'>
          <p>
            <div class='tooltip'>
              xxx
              <span class='tooltiptext'>abcdefg.
                        </span>
            </div>
          </p>
          <select name='xxx'>
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
            <option>c</option>
            <option>d</option>
            <option>e</option>
            <option>f</option>
            <option>g</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class='col'>
          <p>
            <div class='tooltip2'>
              yyy
              <span class='tooltiptext'>abc.
                    </div>
                    </p>
                <select name='yyy'>
                    <option>a</option>
                    <option>b</option>
                    <option>c</option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col'>
                    <p>
                    <div class='tooltip'>
                        zzz
                        <span class='tooltiptext'>abc.
                        </span>
            </div>
          </p>
          <select name='zzz'>
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
            <option>c</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class='col'>
          <p>
            <div class='tooltip2'>
              xxxx
              <span class='tooltiptext'>
                          xxxxxxxx
                        </span>
            </div>
          </p>
          <select name='xxxx'>
            <option>a</option>
            <option>br</option>
            <option>c</option>
            <option>d</option>
            <option>e</option>
            <option>f</option>
            <option>g</option>
            <option>h</option>
            <option>i</option>
            <option>j</option>
            <option>k</option>
            <option>l</option>
            <option>m</option>
            <option>n</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col'>
          <p>
            <div class='tooltip'>
              yyyy
              <span class='tooltiptext'>yyyy
                        </span>
            </div>
          </p>
          <p><input type='text' name='yyyy' required> </p>
        </div>
        <div class='col'>
          <p>
            <div class='tooltip2'>
              zzzz
              <span class='tooltiptext'>zzzz
                        </span>
            </div>
          </p>
          <select name='zzzz'>
            <option>no</option>
            <option>yes</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col'>
          <p>
            <div class='tooltip'>
              xxxxx
              <span class='tooltiptext'>xxxxx
                        </span>
            </div>
          </p>
          <select name='xxxxxt'>
            <option>y</option>
            <option>n</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class='col'>
          <p>
            <div class='tooltip2'>
              yyyyy
              <span class='tooltiptext'>yyyyy
                        </span>
            </div>
          </p>
          <select name='yyyyy'>
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='submit'>
        <p> <input type='submit'> </p>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example `input` elements are wrapped in `p` elements, `select` elements are not, which leads to an inconsistent amount of `p` elements between the rows. Since the default styling for `p` elements includes a bottom and top margin, they affect spacing.

Either use consistent markup for all cells or adjust the styling for `p` elements so that they don't mess up your layout.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that's causing your problem is default browser margin and padding. You just need to remove it.

In your CSS file just add this code at the top & you will be fine.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps you.